# Convert Julian Date CYYDDD to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, date-conversion, jdedwards

I have a column in a table in SQL Server which stores date in Julian format (CYYDDD). I'm running a select SQL on the field and would like to convert the date format to DD/MM/YYYY.

Have tried few SQLs for the format conversion, but none of them give me a correct output

```
DATEADD(dd, (@jdate - ((@jdate/1000) * 1000)) - 1, dateadd(yy, @jdate/1000, 0))

DATEADD(year, XHUPMJ / 1000, 0) + DATEADD(day, XHUPMJ % 1000, 0) - 1
```

Would like to see date output in the format DD/MM/YYYY without any following 0's

I have a Julian Date value in the column as `115351` and I'm expecting it to convert to `17/12/2015`

Comment: Can you please share a sample value for Julian date and the expected value in your required format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a sample code from this [site](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/does-sql-server-have-any-built-functions-work-julian-dates), to convert the Julian Date to DD/MM/YYYY format

```
DECLARE @Sample AS VARCHAR(6) = '115351'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(INT, @Sample) - ((1000*(CONVERT(INT, @Sample)/1000)))-1, DATEADD(YEAR, CONVERT(INT, @Sample/1000), '1 Jan 1900')), 103) AS Result
```

it will convert the 351 th day of the year 2015, so the result will be `17/12/2015`

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e3a6ff4e0c7813573774766e7484a394)

---

**UPDATE:**

As [cars10m suggested in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572698/convert-julian-date-cyyddd-to-dd-mm-yyyy/56572878?noredirect=1#comment99725536_56572878), using `%` Modulus operator, the query above can be reduced as

```
DECLARE @Sample AS VARCHAR(6) = '115351'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(INT, @Sample) % 1000 -1, DATEADD(YEAR, CONVERT(INT, @Sample/1000), '1 Jan 1900')), 103) AS Result
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it gave me output like this .. 2015-12-17 00:00:00.000. Is there a way I can see only the date in the format 17/12/2015.

Comment: In general, the query should return a date or datetime, which this one is. The formatting of that should be done in whatever tool you are using. if you bring it back as a formatted string it makes it hard for other tools to select dates, sort them, etc.

Comment: @Sam Please check my updated query or demo, it will return the output in `DD/MM/YYYY` format

Comment: @ArulKumar, that worked !!! I got the output as expected. Thank you so much for your inputs.

Comment: As of SQL-Server R2008 you can use modulo calculation and shorten `CONVERT(INT, @Sample) - ((1000*(CONVERT(INT, @Sample)/1000)))` to `CONVERT(INT, @Sample) %1000`.

Comment: @cars10m Thanks for the suggestion, updated your point in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this answer you want?

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, CAST(RIGHT(Variable,3) AS int) / 1, CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(Variable,2) + '0101', 103))
```

Comment: No.. the value I have in the column is 115351 and I'm looking to convert it to 17/12/2015.

Comment: I got the output like this 2011-12-17 00:00:00.000. But this is not the correct calendar date and I'm looking for output in the format 17/12/2015. Really appreciate your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing my old hat into an old ring.  It's a variation of what @Arulkumar posted but doesn't require any INT conversions because it starts as an INT.

```
--===== This would be the parameter for an iTVF.
DECLARE @JdeDate INT = 115351    
;
--===== Formula to convert the JDE date to a normal DATETIME and then format it to 
     -- If you want it to be a DATE datatype, convert it one more time.
     -- "-1" is the DATE SERIAL NUMBER for the day before 1900-01-01, which effective subtracts 1 day.
 SELECT [DD/MM/YYYY] = CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(dy,@JdeDate%1000,DATEADD(yy,@JdeDate/1000,-1)),103)
;
```

The final CONVERT may not be necessary if the DATEFORMAT is setup correctly by your Language setup.

The results from the code above look like this...
[image]

Of course, you can pick any column name you'd like and I do recommend turning it into an iTVF (Inline Table Valued Function).  If you have 2019 or better now, it might work as an inlined scalar function but I've not tested it.